# Struggling with a mechanics exam question regarding a circular frictionless slope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

[image]

Source: https://www2.physics.ox.ac.uk/study-here/undergraduates/applications/physics-aptitude-test-pat/pat-past-papers

The answer is either A or B - different mark schemes have different answers (there is no official mark scheme unfortunately). I understand why it must be one of these 2 options, and I suspect it is probably A, but I am struggling to prove it mathematically.

---

Let the slider's height at any time after it is released from rest be $h$.

Let the height of S above the ground be $H$.

Let the point on the circular track such that the tangent to the track at that point is perpendicular to the ground and the height of the point above the ground is $\frac{1}{2}H$ be U.

Let the slider's energy at any point be $E$.

The track is frictionless, so $E$ is constant.

$$E=mgH=mgh + \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

If we assume the object reaches T, then at that point:

$$h=H$$
$$mgH=mgH + \frac{1}{2}mv^2$$
$$v=0$$

If $v=0$ then logically the only thing that can happen is that the slider will fall straight down, so C and D are disqualified as options.

However, if the slider goes up the track, slows down and then slides back down the track without reaching T, then it will be instantaneously at rest before it begins to slide back down, which is impossible because $v$ will be $0$ before $h=H$.

Therefore, either the slider falls off the track between U and T (it is logically impossible for it to fall off before U) or it continues to T and falls straight down.

I am struggling to find a mathematical solution to as to which option is correct.

Comment: Why is this question off topic? It fulfils every requirement. It's about a specific concept and shows effort to work through the problem. You could at least explain why before down voting, putting on hold and then going away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slider cannot have a speed of zero while touching T. The reason is that after passing U, its velocity acquires a leftward component, and there is no force acting in the rightward direction that could possibly decrease this component.

Since you proved using conservation of energy that the slider cannot have a *non*zero speed while touching T, the slider cannot touch T.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. It's actually a pretty simple solution - I guess sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitational potential energy only depends on the initial and final positions(vertical).So since S and T are at the same position,gravitational potential energy is the same for both.
Since the slider starts with no initial velocity, $E=mgh,$ at S, At the bottom of the circular track, the slider attains its maximum velocity(least height the slider can be found), at this point, $E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2.$ Since $E=mgh$ at $T, \frac{1}{2}mv^2=0$  at T,but it never gets to T, as something interesting happens.
We can think of the circular track as the  path of a simple pendulum.A torque is exerted on the slider about the center of the circular track(in the context of the simple pendulum).The normal reaction has a component parallel to the gravitational force.In fact we can postulate, that gravitational force exerts a torque in a direction to offset the imbalance in forces parallel to the direction of gravity.i.e imbalance of forces between gravitational force and normal reaction.So how do we obtain the normal reaction at every point?We resolve gravity to a direction normal to the circular track,the force obtained after resolution is equivalent in magnitude to the normal force, but in an opposite direction.Until the point U, a resolution of gravitational force acting on the slider normal to the circular track always gives a positive value($F_g cos(\theta)$, $\theta\leq 90^o $) (meanwhile this force creates the normal reaction), As the slider moves beyond point U.A resolution of the gravitational force gives a negative value,($F_g cos(\theta)$, $\theta\geq 90^o $).We need a positive component to create a definite normal reaction,without this, we have an undefined normal reaction(non-existent,non-existent in this case does not mean zero).Note that gravitational potential energy is not the only factor at play here, the slider must remain on the circular track while the energy transformation takes place.The normal reaction ensures this.